Why is reading the length property of a string in JavaScript O(1) and not O(n)
Strings are primitives, meaning they don't actually have methods or properties associated with them. According to MDN

In contexts where a method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and call the method or perform the property lookup on the wrapper object instead.

So if I'm understanding correctly, whenever you read the length property of a string primitive, JS under the hood creates a new instance of the String object from that passed in string. In other words, when I write this code
console.log('hello world'.length);

javascript does this
const stringObject = new String('hello world');
console.log(stringObject.length);

But since a string primitive doesn't have a length property, doesn't that mean that the length has to be calculated directly whenever you're instantiating the string object? In other words, I would think it has to get recalculated every time you read the length property. I'd also guess that calculating the length property for that object would take linear time.
But the few sources I found say that reading the length property has O(1) time complexity, so what am I misunderstanding? Unfortunately, I'm not smart enough to interpret the source code, but I'm pretty curious about how it all works.

IMO, if I implement the string class myself, I will calculate the length and put the result in the length field as soon as the string is created/the memory is allocated. So, I don't have to re-calculate the length every time i access it.
So, the time to access this integer is O(1).

Everything in js is an object with there properties of own, even string ,This is known as autoboxing, if you check its prototype you'll see a lot of properties along with it, and among those properties there is Length which is already updated or saved there so that you can just fetch it, instead of looping through it to get the length hence not O(n) and thats why O(1)

@Spidy primitives in JavaScript are not objects. They are turned into objects when necessary, at least conceptually, as you say, but strings and numbers are not objects.

@Pointy of course they are not object (by default) its JavaScript which takes care of this and converts it into an object under the hood, JavaScript automatically wraps these primitive values in a String object when you try to access a property or a method.
Now I could be really wrong but this was my understanding so far , as i check the object in browser my self, how else will you explain the object like invoking of length property though?

Yes, primitives are conceptually wrapped in objects when necessary. (Whether the runtime really wraps them in objects, we don't have to know.) But the fact that they need to be wrapped highlights the fact that primitives like strings and numbers are not objects.

@Pointy ofcourse never doubted that fact, just that the end result does end up being an object maybe temporarily but yeah

Why would it take linear time to get the length of a string primitive? This suggests that you are imagining a search for a null terminator, but JavaScript strings are not null terminated. "a\0b" is a string of length 3.

@TszLam For sure, but the thing is, string primitives are not instances of the String class. They're primitives, so they can't store property values. When JS reads the length property of a string primitive, it wraps the primitive in a String object and then creates a length property on that object. And that's the part that confuses me, because I assumed that operation would be linear time.

@Spidy So, as I understand it, autoboxing happens each time a property or method is called on a primitive, right? So whenever you're reading the length property, a new String object has to be instantiated first. So how/where is the length property stored if that object containing the length property is created when .length is called?

@RaymondChen tbh I don't know what a null terminator is. I just assumed it had to be a linear operation because you have to loop over the string to count the number of characters in it. Is there something else happening that allows it to be a constant time operation?

And how do you know when you have found the last character? Are you imagining that JavaScript engine searches for the second quotation mark? That happened at parse time not run time. The parser then saves the characters into a string primitive, and clearly it has to record the length so it knows how many characters to use when wrapping it in an object.

Even an unboxed string has an explicit length. You would only need to count if strings are represented with some kind of terminator character that you have to search for, as in C strings.

Because length is a property of String. It needs O(1) time to get it's value.

In fact
"string".length;
["hello"].length

are built in property inside of string and array prototypes and this value being calculated has nothing to do with array or the string size due to this fact O(1) is correct for this.
